# Is it thread safe when adding FiterProvider on objectMapper on perRequest basis in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have following  way of adding Custom Object Mapper.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.CMSMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jsonMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

and then in controller I am using

@Autowired
  private ObjectMapper jsonMapper;

in one of the action methods I am

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Response get(){
    jsonMapper.setFilters(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(dynamic_per_request));
    return service.get();
}
```

I am just worried it will not be thread safe. Is it true? If yes how can I make it thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not handle it that way. You are changing configuration on the fly, but it is quite possible that another request comes by and changes it to something else before first request has actually used the filter.

Instead, you should implement thread-safe FilterProvider that can resolve your filters dynamically, using something like `ThreadLocal` for passing information you need to pass.

Comment: will it be thread safe  I make scope as per request? Also can I make it scope as per request if it is used by mvc itself?

Comment: I don't use SpringMVC, I have no idea. But `ObjectMapper` is expensive enough that you don't want to get one created per request. You could store `ObjectMapper` in `ThreadLocal` as an alternative.